# Cache replication

Tags: java, replication, ehcache

I'm using EhCache 2.10.2. Synchronous replication (replicateAsynchronously=false) between two servers (S1 and S2).

I have next situation:

1. First HTTP request going to S1
2. S1 can't find object in cache and loads it from DB with state "A" and puts to cache
3. S1 changes object's state to "B", saves to DB and puts to cache
4. S1 sends success response
5. Next request going to S2
6. S2 finds obect in cache with state "A"
7. S2 sends error response, because object must have state "B" on second request.

When server puts object to cache, thread blocked on put operation only to send serialized object to another server, and don't wait while another server deserialize and put element to cache.
So at point 6 can be state "A" or "B", if we get lucky.

Is it possible to configure EhCache to block operations until changes replicated on all nodes?

May be I need to replace EhCache with other cache implementation, or change everything?

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is a weakness of cache replication. Your scenario seems to require strong consistency.

Note that in addition of lacking strong consistency, cache replication does not even guarantee ordering of events on a per key basis nor will it perform any kind of conflict resolution. It is really last update wins.

The only feature of Ehcache that will give you the proper guarantees is [Terracotta clustering](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog). In order to deploy this solution, you will need at least one additional server/JVM to act as the Terracotta cluster.